# Mini page parts are not properly arranged

Tags: minipage

Question: I am dealing with minipage and the problem is parts of minipage are not placed perfectly looks very bad. What is the solution.

What I have done so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{minipage}{.25\textwidth}
For (i)

    $\dfrac{PE}{EQ}=\dfrac{3.9}{3}=1.3$

    $\dfrac{PF}{FR}=\dfrac{3.6}{2.4}=1.5$

    $\dfrac{PE}{EQ}\neq \dfrac{PF}{FR}$

    Therefore,$EF$ is not parallel to $QR$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw[step=1cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (11,7);
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
    \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(2.6,2.4){F}
    \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm surprised to see you are using such a small space for text and such a large space for the figure. Btw you should use `wrapfigure` for this

Comment: Ok please let me know how can i proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `wrapfigure` is ideal in this case. Note that your figure is not that wide!

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw[step=1cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (11,7);
    \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
    \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
    \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
    \tkzDefPoint(2.6,2.4){F}
    \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
    \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

For (i)
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&=\dfrac{3.9}{3}=1.3\\
    \dfrac{PF}{FR}&=\dfrac{3.6}{2.4}=1.5\\
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&\neq \dfrac{PF}{FR}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\end{document}
```

[image]