# Figure is not placed perfectly

Tags: floats

[Mini page parts are not properly arranged](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487691/mini-page-parts-are-not-properly-arranged)

In above link i found best useful answer. I am asking new question in which i have some issue that in second part figure is dragged down i cant understand that how it is happening?

Codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[step=1cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (11,7);
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(2.6,2.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    For (i)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&=\dfrac{3.9}{3}=1.3\\
    \dfrac{PF}{FR}&=\dfrac{3.6}{2.4}=1.5\\
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&\neq \dfrac{PF}{FR}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(3.2,1.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    For (ii)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{4}{4.5}=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PF}{RF}&=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{PF}{RF}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: For cases like yours I'd recommend using minipages instead of wrapfig.

Answer (score 3):

If you add some lipsum text, you will see that `wrapfigure` produces a great space below the first figure (sigh). However, you can get rid of this space by adding an option `[5]` which means the figure will only be as height as 5 lines of text (note that these lines may be very wide, as in the fractions)

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[5]{r}{6cm} % <=================================
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[step=1cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (11,7);
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(2.6,2.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    For (i)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&=\dfrac{3.9}{3}=1.3\\
    \dfrac{PF}{FR}&=\dfrac{3.6}{2.4}=1.5\\
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&\neq \dfrac{PF}{FR}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(3.2,1.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{wrapfigure}

    For (ii)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{4}{4.5}=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PF}{RF}&=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{PF}{RF}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose i add third part below these two, will it work?

Comment: @Sandy It will always work if you add vertical-height option to every `wrapfigure`. But with such a high number of pictures in only one page, I think gathering all these figures into one `figure` by `subfigure` is the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

With minipages:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-6cm}
    For (i)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&=\dfrac{3.9}{3}=1.3\\
    \dfrac{PF}{FR}&=\dfrac{3.6}{2.4}=1.5\\
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&\neq \dfrac{PF}{FR}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[step=1cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (11,7);
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(2.6,2.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}



    \bigskip
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth-6cm}
    For (ii)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{4}{4.5}=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PF}{RF}&=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{PF}{RF}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{6cm}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(3.2,1.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

---

You could also use the `paracol` package as shown here:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,left=0.7in,right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
%line spacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\headsep=10pt

\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    For (i)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&=\dfrac{3.9}{3}=1.3\\
    \dfrac{PF}{FR}&=\dfrac{3.6}{2.4}=1.5\\
    \dfrac{PE}{EQ}&\neq \dfrac{PF}{FR}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\switchcolumn
        {\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\draw[step=1cm,red,very thin] (-4,-4) grid (11,7);
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(2.6,2.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\switchcolumn
    For (ii)
    \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{4}{4.5}=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PF}{RF}&=\dfrac{8}{9}\\
    \dfrac{PE}{QE}&=\dfrac{PF}{RF}
    \end{align*}
    Therefore, $EF$ is not parallel to $QR$.
\switchcolumn
       { \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(2,3.5){P}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){Q}
        \tkzDefPoint(4,0){R}
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8,1.4){E}
        \tkzDefPoint(3.2,1.4){F}
        \tkzDrawSegments(P,Q Q,R P,R E,F)
        \tkzLabelPoints[above,yshift=0pt](P)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,yshift=4pt](Q)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,yshift=4pt](R)
        \tkzLabelPoints[left,xshift=0pt](E)
        \tkzLabelPoints[right,xshift=00pt](F)
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```